# R: Output of duplicated changes after setkey() in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

In the process of merging two datasets I was checking the data for duplicate entries, using the function `duplicated`. I get two different outputs whether I run `duplicated` before or after `setkey()`. Is this natural behaviour in `data.table`? In my (humble) opinion the number of duplicates should be unchanged by setting the key, which, in my understanding, is just a reordering and indexing of the `data.table`. Am I missing some crucial point?

Thanks alot!

Here is an example `data.table`:

```
> DT
   id x1 x2
1:  A  0  1
2:  A  1  1
3:  B  0  1
4:  B  1  0
5:  C  1  1
6:  C  0  0
```

Runnning `duplicated` on this unkeyed dataset I get the result of no duplicate entries, which seems in order.

```
duplicated(DT)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Then after setting the key with `setkey()` i get the following output,

```
setkey(DT,id)
duplicated(DT)
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

where the function indicates 3 duplicates. I just don't get it...

Here is the code i used to generate the `data.table`

```
set.seed(123)
id <- rep(LETTERS[1:3],each=2)
x1 <- sample(c(0,1),6,T)
x2 <- sample(c(0,1),6,T)
DT <- data.table(id,x1,x2)
```

Comment: Did you actually read the documentation of `?duplicated`? The very first row of the documentation states (I quote) "*duplicated returns a logical vector indicating which rows of a data.table (**by key columns or when no key all columns**)*". So which part creates the confusion here?

Comment: Ok, so I don't understand why the second row is marked as duplicated?

Comment: Because you keyed by the `id` column and in the `id` column you have two `A`s and then two `B` and then two `C`. So the second `A` and the second `B` and the second `C` are dupes.

Comment: Ahh... get it. Though i check for duplicate rows by id.

Comment: ...Or maybe not. So when you key by some column `duplicated` only checks whether there are duplictaes in the  key-column?

Comment: That's what the documentation says...

Comment: Ok. I just read it as it checked for dubs BY the key column. So subsetting the data.table by the key column and checking within each subset for duplicates. Anyways thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: Suggesting it be closed as already answered.

Comment: Should I and an answer?

Comment: Duffau, if you wish, you can answer it yourself and accept it (before the Q gets closed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get `duplicated` to use elements from each column, after setting one or multiple key columns, in the row-wise duplicate check, use

```
duplicated(DT,by=NULL)
> [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

As the documentation states `duplicated` for `data.table` behaves differently from the base-version or when it is handling `data.frames`.

When you set the key with `setkey()` the function `duplicated` only checks the rows in the key-columns for duplicates. In the question only `id` is set as key so only the rows (so in this case, the elements in the column) of `id` are checked for duplicates.

If you specify the `by` argument in `duplicated` the  function checks if the rows, with elements from each of the columns specified in `by`, have duplicated rows below in the table.

By setting `by=NULL` all columns are considered, and the function checks for row-wise duplicates, where the row vectors contain elements from all columns.This mimics the behaviour of `duplicated` when handling `data.frames`.